# could not switch on monitor configuration

Tags: monitor

On my `asus x553` I have wiped the hard drive to eliminate win 8.2 and installed Ubuntu 14.04. On boot up I get the Error message  `could not switch on monitor configuation`  and als `ocould not set configuration for CRTC 63`  My only resolution since my laptop screen was broken by a dropped wine bottle, is to use an external monitor.

My real problem is that the external monitor view is a stretched screen unuseable.  So everytime i boot then type in the terminal

```
xrandr --output vga1 --mode 1024x768
```

so the monitor is configured and useable.  How can i make the computer configure.  I tried  `~/.xprofile`  in the terminal but it says there is not such a file.  Suggestions!!??

Answer (score 0):

For a system-wide configuration create the file `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/45x11-custom_xrandr-settings`

```
sudo nano /etc/X11/Xsession.d/45x11-custom_xrandr-settings
```

and add your configuration

```
xrandr --output vga1 --mode 1024x768
```

---

For a user specific configuration create the file `.xprofile` in your home folder

```
nano ~/.xprofile
```

and add

```
xrandr --output vga1 --mode 1024x768
```

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: Dear AB ,  thanx for your comments and guidance. i hav ebeen pursuing but not successfully ..  seems that i have set up now an xprofile, an xprofile.save and an xprofile save1 !! in my home folder.  seems like on bootup my computer is confused and i have to resort to manually entering the xrandr command everytime i boot. Pleased for more assistance. thnax   Dennis

Comment: But no `.xprofile`?

Comment: Have you tried the systemwide configuration. That would make more sense.

Comment: there is a   .xprofile   and   .xprofile. save    and .xprofile.save1      !      do these conflict?

Comment: No, there is no conflict.

Comment: so i am still having to go to term and type in xrandr line to reset my monitor . there is no reset on boot up

Comment: have not tried system option yet.  that looked more complicated

Comment: No, isn't. Try it. If it fails, simply remove the created file `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/45x11-custom_xrandr-settings`

Comment: ok one last problem, AB.  on boot up all results generate final ubuntu screen without any distortion.  However iget a message before final completion of boot....... it reads   ERROR FOUND WHEN LOADING /HOME/DENNIS/.XPROFILE       WARNING;  OUTPUT VGA1 NOT FOUND; IGNORING      FIX AT EARLIEST feasible OPPORTUNITY